# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Series

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing a single entry from a column of a data frame

2011100101 is interpreted as 1 AM of 1st October 2011.

I want it to change in the format as YYYY-Mmm-dd HH

```
train['date1']=datetime.strptime(train['ID'], '%Y%m%d%H')
```

but getting an error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Series

How to change in the required format for the entire entries in a single column?

Comment: try to print the content of `train['ID']` and you'll why... ;)

Comment: You should use [`pd.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Answer (score 17):

you can use the [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method

```
train['date1'] = train['ID'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d%H'))
```

Comment: Or list comprehension:  train['date1'] = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d%H') for x in train['ID'] ]

Comment: list comprehension looks better

Comment: Three years later, and @Acccumulation's list comprehension answer FTW (for me, anyway)